# Creating a memory-only NSManagedObject model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I need to create an instance of a NSManagedObject that will not be saved in CoreData and only in memory.

e.g.:

I have the `Item` and `Log` NSManagedObject, and they have relations between them.
I want to be able to create a `Log` instance without any core data properties, and assign its `item` property to an `Item` instance.

I know I can create it in a different, memory-persistence, context (or `nil` context). But then I can't assign the `item` property, since my `Item` instance is in the core-data context.

```
NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Log" inManagedObjectContext:defaultContext];
Log *log = [[Log alloc] initWithEntity:description insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
log.item = item;
```

This code throws an exception when ran:

`Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'item' between objects in different contexts`

How can I achieve this in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a NSManagedObjectContext with parent context set to your Log's MOC.

Comment: This seems to be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the relationship to have an inverse?  If not, you could use the ObjectID for the item objects as an attribute in the Log entity.  You would need to convert the ObjectID to its URIRepresentation, and then convert that to a NSString:

```
NSURL *itemURI = [item.objectID URIRepresentation];
NSString *itemURIstring = [itemURI absoluteString];
log.itemURI = itemURIstring;
```

(If item has not yet been saved to the database, it will have a temporary ID - you should test for this with `item.objectID.isTemporary` otherwise the objectID may change).  When you want to find the Item object for a given Log object, reverse the process:

```
NSURL *itemURI = [NSURL URLwithString:log.itemURI];
NSManagedObjectID *itemObjectID = [self.context.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:itemURI];
Item *item = [self.context objectWithID:itemObjectID];
```

Pretty cumbersome!

I guess if you need an inverse, you could do the same (i.e. store a URI for the Log object as a string in Item).